How do we know if a ps1 file is executed from CLI or GUI?
When a ps1 file is executed, how do we know that the file is executed from CLI command line or from GUI Explorer (the file itself or another ps1 file)?
There are several reasons I ask this. One thing is that we need pause to read the output, but we don't need it if execute from CLI.
For example, this file:
# Test.ps1
#$FromCLI = 
if ($FromCLI) {'Executed From CLI'} else {'Executed From PS1 File; pause'}

What code is needed in $FromCLI=?
So that we can differentiate between executed from CLI or GUI (ps1 file).

Does Is it possible to know if a PowerShell script is launched from GUI or console? - Stack Overflow and/or Is it possible to know if a PowerShell script is launched from GUI or console? - Stack Overflow answer your question?

-@DavidPostill I have tried by looking SHost. Not worked.

Play with these $Host | Select-Object *; $MyInvocation.ScriptName; $MyInvocation.InvocationName; $MyInvocation.Line; $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name; $MyInvocation | Select-Object *; to see if you can work it out.... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.4#myinvocation

-@VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Oke. Thanks.

You can remove the ChatGPT code.  It does nothing.

For your main question, you can use something like this to get a simple true/false value:
# check if running from CLI window or launched from explorer context menu
$fromCLI = $host.Name -eq "ConsoleHost" -and -not ($MyInvocation.Line -like "if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned')*")


Depending on why you need this, there  are some other things you might want to check though. Here's an expanded version of what you tried for example, for the most common powershell consoles:
# show console environment
switch ($Host.Name) {
  'ConsoleHost'                 {Write-Host "Running from CLI"}
  'Windows PowerShell ISE Host' {Write-Host "Running from GUI (Windows PowerShell ISE)"}
  'Visual Studio Code Host'     {Write-Host "Running from GUI (VS Code)"}
  default                       {Write-Host "Running from GUI ($_)" }
}

# command used to launch script
$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

# location of running script itself 
$PSScriptRoot

# process .exe location (pwsh.exe/powershell.exe/PowerShell_ISE.exe/etc)
(ps -id $pid).Path

# parent process, for things like windows terminal which just run PS as a child process
try {(ps -id (Get-CimInstance -Cl Win32_Process -F "processId='$pid'").parentProcessId -ea Stop).path} 
catch {"N/A"}

# check for specific automatic variables:
if ($psISE)   {Write-Host "Running from GUI (Windows PowerShell ISE)"}
if ($psEditor){Write-Host "Running from GUI (VS Code)"}

Results in something like:
Running from CLI
C:\folder\check where script was launched from.ps1
C:\folder
C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe
C:\WINDOWS\Explorer.EXE


the output always Running from CLI, when i execute it from Explorer (right click > Run with PowerShell).

@Mr.Key7 That's correct. The "Run with powershell" context menu option just launches the CLI and feeds it the script, like running powershell.exe -File c:\path\to\script.ps1. There may be a way to distinguish it, but you'll need to explain more about what you're trying to accomplish

to my understanding, Explorer is a GUI. Thanks.

@Mr.Key7 The explorer context menu always starts powershell with the same command, which you can look for with something like: if ($MyInvocation.Line -like "if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned')*") { Write-Host "Running from CLI (Windows Explorer)" }

I just want something simple.  differentiate between from PS CLI and PS1 file its self.

@Mr.Key7 I've updated the simple part of my answer to include this, which should do what you're looking for I think. Otherwise, can you describe what you're trying to accomplish? I can clean up the answer better if I understand your workflow and what isn't working for you

This is my goal.
FromCLI= I open PowerShell Commandline, then execute the file using command like .\Test.ps1 or & "path of file"
FromGUI= I execute the file by double-click it (pwsh.exe) or right-click > open with powershell or I execute it from another ps1 file.

When i execute from PS CLI, then the output $True, else $False. It seem simple.

@Mr.Key7 Yes, the first line of my answer does that (except for double-clicking the file - it's exactly the same as opening pwsh.exe console then running your script, so it shows CLI). Generally if you want something different in those scenarios, then your gui/interactive parts should probably be in a separate script file

$LastExitCode
After I tried several automatic variables: $Host $MyInvocation $? $^ $$ $LastExitCode, I found one that suited my purposes. For several calling formats, It's always 1 from CommandLine.
Example: (I don't need pause if from CLI)
# Test.ps1
'Hello World'
if ($LastExitCode -ne 1) {Pause}

From CLI: .\Test.ps1, & .\Test.ps1, & "C:\Temp\Test.ps1".
From Its file or another ps1 file by double click it (pwsh) or right click >run with powershell.
Also tried in Function:
function testF {
    'Hello World'
    if ($LastExitCode -ne 1) {Pause}
}
testF

So. the function can be executed from its file with additional pause. Not needed it from CLI.
The Output from its file:
Hello World
Press Enter to continue...:

The output from CLI:
PS7: .\testF.ps1
Hello World

